# Unwanted Background color/artifact on HTML5 Video Tag

Tags: css, html, video

I've used Video Tag on a landing page of our upcoming site [Levoma](http://levoma.com). I've also used SublimeVideo to have some extra control on my video.

**ISSUE:** I see some sort of an artifact on Chrome, ever since I upgraded to the latest version (10.0.648.204) - the background on the video is no longer white (the video used have white background). I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.x.

There is no problem with Firefox, Safari, Opera. My friends says, there are no issues with Chrome on Windows too.

Any idea what might be causing this? I've attached a screenshot. [image: Background Issues of Levoma.com on Chrome Browser]

*Note:* I've tried setting background #fff to almost all the elements associated with that video tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently it is a bug.
this may give you some insight to whats going on

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73234&q=html5%20video%20colors&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS

Comment: I don't have a mac, so one could try testing the video with the newer version of chrome, which can be found [here](http://goo.gl/6SjdM) (click on the last folder and then download the `.zip` file).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the bug is gone in the latest Chromium. Any idea if I can force/hack this to work nicely in the current version of chrome (via CSS, Video tag parameters, javascript)?