# Chrome Html5 video can't display white, has gray background

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, html5-video

We have an intro page which plays a html5 video before the main site content is displayed.
The video has a white background so it integrates seemlessly with the page background.
However, in the chrome browser the whole video has a gray background.

Apparently, these questions from 2011 indicate this was/is a bug in chromium. They also state the bug was gone in the latest chrome update. However, I downloaded the latest chrome version, 27.0.1453.110 m, and the problem is still there?

[html 5- Videos - White is washed off in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858424/html-5-videos-white-is-washed-off-in-chrome)

[Unwanted Background color/artifact on HTML5 Video Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544032/unwanted-background-color-artifact-on-html5-video-tag)

[image]

Does anyone have any solution or workaround for this problem ? ... This bug renders our whole project useless ... It seems unbelievable to me that despite of the html5 hype, chrome can't play whites in videos since 2011 ??

....... EDIT ....................................................

Ok, I've created a jsfiddle project :
http://jsfiddle.net/Ykmya/5/

```
<body>
<video id="introVideo" width="774" height="400"  oncanplay="playIntroVideo()">
    <source src="http://users.telenet.be/A-I/ChromeBugTest.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Uw browser ondersteunt geen html5 video
</video>
</body>
```

When viewed with Chrome, you will see the gray background

........ EDIT 2 ..................................................

using pandavengers answer, I added this css, which has an acceptable result :

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    video{ -webkit-filter: brightness(108.5%); }
}
```

Comment: Can you setup new jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Kristian, i've created the jsfidlle project ...

Comment: Thanks, but video won't load here... can you check?

Comment: No, it only seems to load in Chrome on the jsfiddle website. I've tested the code locally, and apparantly Firefox doesn't want to load external mp4 files .. If I change the src to a local mp4 (same file), it loads without problems ... Dont ask me why :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ykmya/8/

Here's a simple fix, I simply upped the brightness using a webkit filter. I was going to draw it onto canvas and then filter the pixels, which should be much smoother, but I cannot access your video through cross-domains. Instead I just used the css style

```
video{
     -webkit-filter: brightness(108.5%); 
}
```

Edit: This has been fixed on the latest version of Chrome I believe.

Comment: I took an screenshot and then used Paint to read the RGB values and they are relatively close (+/- 1) to the intended values

Comment: you might want to create Javascript to check the browser is Chrome and not anything else and THEN apply the filter, my example is just an extremely simplified example

Comment: I think this selector applies the filter only to webkit browsers, namely Chrome and safari : @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {}

Comment: yeah, I was just afraid safari videos might become very bright. well, good luck!

Comment: This works, thanks!  108.5% was a little intense.  I found that 101% was closer to the original values for my project.

Comment: @Brian AFAIK the video brightness issue has been fixed a long time ago. You no longer need to compensate for anything and setting 101% is not necessary. My answer was simply a temporary workaround for a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @pandavenger nope - it's not completely fixed, but it's definitely graphics card dependent or something else environmental :-(

Comment: @Simon_Weaver ah man, that sucks, I haven't encountered an issue like it for a while, thanks for informing me though.

Comment: bigger issue on powerful machines with crazy graphics setups. most laptops I've tested are very light gray or white. has been verified on 4 machines now, in two separate environments (all graphics people). ipad / Mac is 100% white

Comment: In my instance the video on Chrome was displaying too dark. I set brightness(100%) and this fixed it without breaking it on Firefox (where it was already working ok)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with backgrounds in browsers from multiple vendors. Dark background in firefox on windows and chrome on mac.

I ended up creating 2 versions of the video

WebM -> Non IE
mp4 -> All IE

And then set the video ordering using conditional comments

```
 <!--[if !IE]><!-->
   <source src="Content/Video/1.webmsd.webm" />
   <source src="Content/Video/1.mp4" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE]><!-->
    <source src="Content/Video/1.mp4" />
    <source src="Content/Video/1.webmsd.webm" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```