# HTML5 .mp4 video - IE & xiaomi issue - turns white into gray

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mp4

It seems that when playing my HTML5 video in IE9+ the white colors in my .mp4 for some weird reason turns gray.

The video plays and shows correctly in Firefox, Crome + smartphones.

**ISSUE:** In IE white turns into gray. Note: The generated video files is a recording from another page with a solid white background, so no chance of conflict with some weird transparent background attempt.

[image: Video white turns into gray]

**Image 1** shows the correct look from Firefox, Crome etc..
**Image 2** is a screenshot from after having started the video in IE9.

As a reference, this is my HTML:

```
<video width="552" height="572" poster="video/clip.png" preload="none" id="video">
    <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/clip.mp4" />
    <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
    <source type="video/webm" src="video/clip.webm" />
    <!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
    <source type="video/ogg" src="video/clip.ogv" />
    <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
    <object width="552" height="572" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="video/player.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="video/player.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=clip.mp4" />
        <!-- Image as a last resort -->
        <img src="video/clip.png" width="552" height="572" title="No video playback capabilities" />
        <p>Your browser can&rsquo;t play HTML5 video. <a href="video/clip.ogv">Download it</a> instead.</p>
    </object>
</video>
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

EDIT:
- Thought it could be something with the encoding. But the clip is original saved as format: H.264. Also tried running it through again as format H.264, but same result.

Really clueless why this color change happens in EI

Comment: Same issue here, white bg of mp4 video (H264) is displayed gray, not solved yet. I was reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983018/chrome-html5-video-cant-display-white-has-gray-background) that you can solve this by CSS `filter: brightness(108.5%);` but it did not work for IE11. Maybe you can give it a try with your OS/browser?

Comment: Hey Echt Einfach TV - I never found a solution for this either. I also tried out the CSS filter with no luck at all. It's a very weird issue :/

Comment: Yes, which does not allow me to use HTML5 videos for my users! :(

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly an IE specific bug that unfortunately does not seem to have a workaround. Unless IE 11 has support for OGG or WebM, it looks like you'll have to use a flash fallback, which is pretty counter-intuitive considering how far HTML5 has come.

If IE **does** support another type of video that can be played in the browser, I'd suggest using an HTML5 video with a fallback source of the different video.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I thought I would update it with the problem. The problem here is with Hardware Acceleration, which is on by default. Turn off hardware acceleration (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2528233) and the video will be white again.

I do not know how to fix this though.

EDIT : Further investigation points to being AMD Radeon specific (I cant confirm this).

Comment: Hi jagdipa - thanks for looking into to this.
Im on a MSI GFX card + motherboard and testing this again, still shows the issue. HOWEVER now everything is fine in IE, but looks gray in Firefox + Chrome, lol

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error on a Xiaomi smartphone.

Adding the following css did the trick

```css
video {
 filter: brightness(108.5%);
}
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983018/chrome-html5-video-cant-display-white-has-gray-background). Thx to @avatar for his comment.