# Background color on video changes on different screens

Tags: css, html, video

EDIT: SOLUTION: [Chrome Html5 video can't display white, has gray background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983018/chrome-html5-video-cant-display-white-has-gray-background)

I made a video intro for the web [www.davidusandizaga.com](http://www.davidusandizaga.com)

This is the result visiting the web from my laptop, firefox and mozilla:
[image: laptop]

And this is the result from my desktop, firefox and mozilla:
[image: desktop]

Video's background is completely white, and got no idea why on my desktop it is blue, and not on my laptop. I changed manually browser's width to make it the same my laptop's (maybe it could be loosing color properties when adjusting video's height to quite bigger heights than video's original height?) but background on video keeps blue.

Here you have the original video: http://davidusandizaga.com/presen.mp4

And this is how it is inserted:

HTML:

```
<div class="background">
         <video preload="auto" autoplay muted class="indexVideo">     
            <source src="presen.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         </video>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
video{
   opacity:0;
}

.background{
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   height:100%;
   width:auto;
   opacity:0.4;
}
```

Apart from creating the other two video formats needed (its pending), and setting an image in case video is not loaded, you see any other bad practice in here?

Comment: It's not white on Chrome. I'd say it's a video stage color issue. Even the raw video background loaded is not white.

Comment: yes, both on fiurefox and chrome it is not white, but it is when getting in by my laptop.. it is right the same resource.

Comment: @Aibrean Video issue meaning must re-record? Is that something you can adjust with software?

Comment: I have searched for "video stage color issues" and seems not to be much info about this..